# What does ".swap" in "swap!" source code do?

Tags: clojure

I was curious so I checked source code of swap! function on clojure repository, and it was like this:

```
(defn swap!
  "Atomically swaps the value of atom to be:
  (apply f current-value-of-atom args). Note that f may be called
  multiple times, and thus should be free of side effects.  Returns
  the value that was swapped in."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([^clojure.lang.Atom atom f] (.swap atom f))
  ([^clojure.lang.Atom atom f x] (.swap atom f x))
  ([^clojure.lang.Atom atom f x y] (.swap atom f x y))
  ([^clojure.lang.Atom atom f x y & args] (.swap atom f x y args)))
```

And I don't know what the "**.swap**" function is doing? I tried to search for it but it's not defined in the same file, so can't find definition of it. Or is this another special thing that is actually not a function at all?

Comment: [The code pieces you wanted](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java#L33). As you could derive from type hints, they reside in clojure.lang.Atom (you may want to scroll down a little bit -- there are multiple overloads of .swap).

Comment: if you'r interested, here are the overloads of swap https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/8fda34e4c77cac079b711da59d5fe49b74605553/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java#L33

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Clojure, an expression `(.x object a b c)` results in a method call, which in Java would be expressed as `object.x(a, b, c)`. For more details see [*Java Interop*](http://clojure.org/java_interop).

In this particular case, the `swap!` function calls an appropriately overloaded [`swap`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/8fda34e4/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java#L33) method of the `clojure.lang.Atom` instance passed as the first argument. The `swap` method contains the actual logic performing the swap.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of things in *Clojure* are actually implemented in *Java*, like reference types (atom, ref, var, agent), data structures (map, vector, list, set), namespaces (the actual `Namespace` class) and other stuff. When reading the source code for *Clojure* functions in `clojure.core` it's not rare to find an interop call to a *Java* method.

It is my understanding that there's a long term objective to implement these things in *Clojure* itself (search [here](http://clojure.org/todo) for *Clojure-in-Clojure*), but for now these things are implemented in `Java`, which is really not so bad since the whole language is open source and you can check any implementation detail online in the github repo (already linked in a comment): [Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/master/src) (note that there's a `jvm` and a `clj` folder indicating in what language the code inside is implemented).

Comment: Didn't know that even atom is implemented in java. Although the other answer is exactly what I wanted, your answer let me learned new thing as well, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, an atom is sth. that is under control of transactional memory. (Read about STM, please.) It is inmutable for its observers (dereferencing an atom returns inmutable state as of the instant of deref), but can be mutated transactionally. This is exactly what swap! does. It transactionally swaps the old value for the new value. Please note that it is very different from assignment. Assignment is not safe for concurrency.

In other words, atom works like a cell in a database table. When you query it, you will have a value, not an exception, even if at the same instant another query is updating it.

Cheers -

Comment: Well, guess I didn't state my question clearly so many fine fellows tried to explain swap! and atom :-) I was looking for the swap! function's actual source code, to check if swap! behaves as it is described on my book... then I saw the ".swap" in swap!'s source code, I didn't know ".swap" so I couldn't understand the code, now I see it's java method call lol. But I did read about STM & ref & atom before posting question though.